# How do you determine which WS method was called based on Request.InputStream?

Tags: c#, web-services, inputstream, httpmodule

Within a HttpModule, I'd like to figure out which web method was called/intercepted and act based on that. For example, if I called WebMethod1, do something, yet do nothing for WebMethod2.

If I look at soap:Header and soap:Body, I can see the method name but would it be alright to parse the soap:Envelope and if so, which part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two method have a common endpoint you need to parse the SOAP message to determine what method is called. In this case you need to check the `<soap:Body>` tag and find the operation name that is the first element name that belongs to the body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code that parses the soap message:

```
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc=new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(soapMessage);

    foreach (XmlNode xn in doc)
    {
        foreach (XmlElement element in xn)
        {
            if (element.Name == "soap:Body")
                result = element.FirstChild.Name;
        }
    }

    return result;
```